# Derivative log problem

Tags: calculus

I have:
$$\ln(ax + b)^4$$

After calculating ($u'$/$u$) I get:

$$4/(ax+b)$$ but the solution is $$4a/(ax+b)$$

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

PS: $a$ and $b$ are $\mathbb R^+ $

Comment: You need to apply the chain rule more carefully.  Go through all of your steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the chain rule, using $\frac{d}{dx}(ax+b)=a$.  (That is your missing factor of $a$.) I can't tell whether you did so, but you can also simplify the first expression to $4\log(ax+b)$.

Comment: Ohhhh! Thanks, I must be tired!